# How to autoload Service provider in Laravel package development

Tags: laravel, package-development

I'm trying to develop a very simple Laravel package for learning purpose. I want to display a simple message like '`Hello World`' when I call `/demo` route. I've installed my package in a Laravel project with the following command:

```
composer require onbiponi/message:dev-master
```

And then,

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Now,  I can't access `/demo` route. I get the error:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

I noticed the `boot` method of `MessageServiceProvider` is not being triggered. Do I need to manually add this service provider to `config/app.php` or do I need need to add something manually? But I want to do everything automatically after installation.
Here is my package in github: https://github.com/rejauldu/message

Comment: I take it you're using Laravel 5.4 (looking at the minimum laravel version for your `composer.json`)?

Comment: yes. I'm using Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoload service provider only exist from Laravel 5.5.
It will not work with 5.4